# how to use 26 in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

I'm trying to print  A-Z

in the code `MOV CX,[34H]` how come the CX has equivalent of 26? when i used that code it gave me the output from A-Z

```
TITLE SAMPLE PROGRAM USING CMP AND JMP
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 0100H
.DATA

.CODE
START:

        MOV AX,@DATA
        MOV DS,AX

        MOV AH,02H

        MOV CX,[34H]
        MOV DL,41H

START_LOOP:        

        INT 21H

        INC DL
        DEC CX

        JZ EXIT

        LOOP START_LOOP 



EXIT:   MOV AX,4C00H
        INT 21H


END START
```

Comment: What value does that instruction put into CX, when you check with a debugger?  And does it assemble to a load from address 34H, or to a mov-immediate?  I think in MASM-style syntax, it's still an immediate even with the `[]`.

Comment: Why do you have a `LOOP` directly following `DEC CX`/`JZ`?

Comment: because 34h is 52 ... 52/2 = 26 ... together with MASM it suddenly all makes sense... Can somebody burn all MASM binaries from the Earth, before it will lay eggs? (`dec cx` + `loop` will decrement cx by two for every loop iteration, so the loop will repeat only 26 times before `loop` will skip due to cx being zero.)

Comment: Letter `'A'` is set by `MOV DL,41H` ('A' == 41h == 65). Then every loop iteration the `dl` is incremented by `INC DL`. So it goes `'B'`, `'C'`, ... There's 26 letters in English alphabet, thus looping 26 times will end with `'Z'` output, and `dl` equals `'['` after loop. Check ASCII table, if unsure where the `[` comes from and why `A` is 65.

Comment: Do three changes : replace `MOV CX,[34H]` by `MOV CX,26`, and remove `DEC CX` and `JZ EXIT`.

Comment: `34h` *is* `52`. And that *is* `110100` in binary, and `64` in octal ... it's the same value `52` (in decimal = most common human format), written in different base formatting. The trailing "h" in `34h` means the number is in hexadecimal (base 16) formatting, so "digits" 0123456789ABCDEF are used to encode value. The converting to decimal you do 3*16 + 4 = 52. (assembler converts it for computer to current signals in "bits", which can be best imagined when compared to binary formatting, that's native formatting for CPU 1/0 in particular bit). 'A' is converted to number value by ASCII table def

Comment: Outputting 20h (you can write directly `' '` in source) character is correct idea, so you must have some other problem in the logic of your code, maybe not restoring the `dl` back to letter, or whatever. Use debugger to see your code in action and all register values after each instruction step by step.

Comment: @Ped7g here's my code now. i cant figure out what to do. i already tried to put the MOV DX, 20H INT 21 everywhere but still it outputs AABBCCDD and so on instead of A B C D ...

START:


        MOV AX,@DATA

        MOV DS,AX

        
        MOV AH,02H


        MOV CX,26

        MOV DL,41H

        

START_LOOP:
        

        INT 21H

        MOV DH,20H

        INT 21H

        INC DL
        
LOOP START_LOOP

Answer (score 1):

*[34H]* is address, pointer.
You take value by address 34h. Somehow, there is 26.

Comment: MASM trap.. it will be assembled as `mov cx,34h` even with `[]`.

Comment: The controversial statement. It is not at least MASM.

Comment: From further comments from OP it become apparent he's using MASM (or TASM in quirk mode), so it really gets assembled as `mov cx,52` for him. But otherwise you would be completely correct, and it was recommended to OP to "fix" that line anyway, to have less confusing source. (It hurts my eyes too, I mean, I can somehow understand what they did to `mov cx,var`, even if I disagree strongly. But this ignoring of `[]` ... what were they thinking? Then I recall it's Microsoft.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code fixed :

```
.MODEL SMALL 
.STACK 0100H 
.DATA

.CODE START:

    MOV AX,@DATA
    MOV DS,AX

    MOV AH,02H

    MOV CX,26
    MOV DL,41H

START_LOOP:

    INT 21H
    PUSH DX          ◄■■■ PRESERVE CURRENT LETTER.
    MOV DL,20h       ◄■■■ DL, NOT DH
    INT 21H
    POP DX           ◄■■■ RESTORE CURRENT LETTER.
    INC DL

    LOOP START_LOOP

EXIT:
    MOV AX,4C00H
    INT 21H
```

**Edit :** AaBbCc...

```
.MODEL SMALL 
.STACK 0100H 
.DATA     

upper db 'A'          ◄■■■ VARIABLES TO CONTROL
lower db 'a'          ◄■■■ UPPER AND LOWERCASE LETTER.

.CODE START:

    MOV AX,@DATA
    MOV DS,AX

    MOV AH,02H

    MOV CX,26

START_LOOP:

    MOV DL,upper
    INT 21H                ◄■■■ DISPLAY UPPERCASE LETTER.
    MOV DL,lower
    INT 21H                ◄■■■ DISPLAY LOWERCASE LETTER.     

    INC upper              ◄■■■ NEXT UPPERCASE LETTER.
    INC lower              ◄■■■ NEXT LOWERCASE LETTER.

    LOOP START_LOOP

EXIT:
    MOV AX,4C00H
    INT 21H
```

Comment: okay thanks,how about AaBb, how can i also increment the 61h for letter a?

Comment: how? i have no idea.

Comment: @grace BTW, if you will check ASCII table closely, you may notice that to change case of letter means only to flip single bit (ASCII table is intentionally defined as that, also letters can be distinguished from digits by simple bit test, etc.. several other bit tricks possible). So "AaBb..." version can be done with single variable/register (`dl`) going from A to Z only, with flipping the bit for lower/upper case switch. It's then actually simpler than the "space" version, where you had to "destroy" content of `dl` by 20h during output of space. Try to change the "AB..." version like this.